# Import public key (plain text) into Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, encryption, microsoft-outlook-2010, public-key-encryption

I have a public key:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

...

-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Is there any possibility to use this public key in Outlook 2010, without any add-ins? I know about [gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.de/), but Outlook has also the possibility to send signed and encrypted E-Mails using certificats.

So, is it possible to convert a PGP PUBLIC KEY to a certificate, such that Outlook 2010 understands it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PGP and S/MIME are completely independend crypto systems. While both use certificates that carry similar parameters for RSA or such, trying to "convert" from one to another still makes as little sense as trying to convert a piano to a guitar just because both use strings.

So, even if you manage to create an X.509 certificate for S/MIME containing the same RSA parameters as the existing PGP certificate, it'll remain useless because the recipient couldn't decrypt it using their PGP tools anyway. *(They'd need to do the same kind of conversion, and at this point, if they wanted to use S/MIME, they wouldn't have sent you a PGP cert in the first place.)*

Comment: Thanks! So I can go the "Outlook" way, or use an add-in that supports PGP?